# Why ERB doesn't not render this line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm rendering a erb template outside Rails. The template is to be saved as an html file and sent elsewhere, so in my code I have this:

```
erb_file = "templates/banners/#{template}.html.erb"

erb_str = File.read(erb_file)

@city = options[:city]
@address = "#{@campaign.open_house_day} #{@case.open_house_from.strftime('%d/%m')} kl. #{@case.open_house_from.strftime('%H.%M')}-#{@case.open_house_to.strftime('%H.%M')}"
... 

renderer = ERB.new(erb_str)
result = renderer.result(binding)

FileUtils.mkdir_p('temp') unless File.directory?('temp')

File.open('temp/index.html', 'w') do |f|
  f.write(result)
end
```

All content is rendered fine, but erb simply ignore `@address` variable. Any ideas of why? While in my code, if I do `puts @address` the output is a string as expected. If I do `puts @address.class` the output is a String. Wha am I missing?

Please note that the above does not use Rails

**EDIT**

Here's the line in my template that I use to render the html:

```
<span class="wday"><%= @address %></span>
```

Comment: Do you use @address? If so, where and how exactly?

Comment: @Eric Duminil I've added the snippet of template that renders that string

Comment: A [mcve] will help greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing I can think of is you're not setting the instance variable in the same scope as the ERB rendering.

You can also try this to define `address` in the ERB:

```
# make sure address is set first
# if it's not, you have a scoping problem
raise(ArgumentError) if @address.nil?

binding.local_variable_set :address, @address

puts ERB.new("<%= address %>").result binding
```